# Regex to extract 1st word and replace One by 1

Tags: web, web-scraping

I am extracting some data and some of the output can be like this:

One person found this helpful
4 people found this helpful

I am looking for a regex to extract the 1st word and if the 1st word is One, replace it with 1

For the above, output will be:
One person found this helpful: 1
4 people found this helpful: 4

Thanks

Comment: If you've so far tried something. Could you share it with the SO community. We can help you improve. It's just that it would be much appreciated to know that you've atleast made an attempt and tried something on your own before making this post.

Comment: I can extract the 1st word but not able to replace One by 1. To extract first word, regex is: ^([\w\-]+)